# Electron-notarize problem not signing all binaries

Tags: electron

I'm having strange problems with electron notarization.
I followed the tutorial on this page:https://kilianvalkhof.com/2019/electron/notarizing-your-electron-application/

It seemed to be pretty thorough so I don't know what I'm missing.
Everything runs fine until notarize.js:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const { notarize } = require('electron-notarize');

exports.default = async function notarizing(context) {
  const { electronPlatformName, appOutDir } = context;  
  if (electronPlatformName !== 'darwin') {
    return;
  }

  const appName = context.packager.appInfo.productFilename;

  return await notarize({
    appBundleId: 'com.oriolgomez.beatstar',
    appPath: `${appOutDir}/${appName}.app`,
    appleId: process.env.APPLEID,
    appleIdPassword: process.env.APPLEIDPASS,
  });
};
```

The notarization log looks like this:
{
"logFormatVersion": 1,
"jobId": "de0d8e6d-2f5b-4937-b2eb-124b0e831281",
"status": "Invalid",
"statusSummary": "Archive contains critical validation errors",
"statusCode": 4000,
"archiveFilename": "beatstar.zip",
"uploadDate": "2020-10-02T08:02:04Z",
"sha256": "e85e189e57f04af30f21e2040580830167a7f704ea6ab70b8f315e3cc9cb6a80",
"ticketContents": null,
"issues": [
{
"severity": "error",
"code": null,
"path": "beatstar.zip/beatstar.app/Contents/MacOS/beatstar",
"message": "The binary is not signed with a valid Developer ID certificate.",
"docUrl": null,
"architecture": "x86_64"
},
{
"severity": "error",
"code": null,
"path": "beatstar.zip/beatstar.app/Contents/Frameworks/beatstar Helper (GPU).app/Contents/MacOS/beatstar Helper (GPU)",
"message": "The binary is not signed with a valid Developer ID certificate.",
"docUrl": null,
"architecture": "x86_64"
},
{
"severity": "error",
"code": null,
"path": "beatstar.zip/beatstar.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Electron Framework",
"message": "The binary is not signed with a valid Developer ID certificate.",
"docUrl": null,
"architecture": "x86_64"
},
{
"severity": "error",
"code": null,
"path": "beatstar.zip/beatstar.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libEGL.dylib",
"message": "The binary is not signed with a valid Developer ID certificate.",
"docUrl": null,
"architecture": "x86_64"
},
{
"severity": "error",
"code": null,
"path": "beatstar.zip/beatstar.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libswiftshader_libEGL.dylib",
"message": "The binary is not signed with a valid Developer ID certificate.",
"docUrl": null,
"architecture": "x86_64"
},
{
"severity": "error",
"code": null,
"path": "beatstar.zip/beatstar.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libvk_swiftshader.dylib",
"message": "The binary is not signed with a valid Developer ID certificate.",
"docUrl": null,
"architecture": "x86_64"
},
{
"severity": "error",
"code": null,
"path": "beatstar.zip/beatstar.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLESv2.dylib",
"message": "The binary is not signed with a valid Developer ID certificate.",
"docUrl": null,
"architecture": "x86_64"
},
{
"severity": "error",
"code": null,
"path": "beatstar.zip/beatstar.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libswiftshader_libGLESv2.dylib",
"message": "The binary is not signed with a valid Developer ID certificate.",
"docUrl": null,
"architecture": "x86_64"
},
{
"severity": "error",
"code": null,
"path": "beatstar.zip/beatstar.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libffmpeg.dylib",
"message": "The binary is not signed with a valid Developer ID certificate.",
"docUrl": null,
"architecture": "x86_64"
},
{
"severity": "error",
"code": null,
"path": "beatstar.zip/beatstar.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Helpers/chrome_crashpad_handler",
"message": "The binary is not signed with a valid Developer ID certificate.",
"docUrl": null,
"architecture": "x86_64"
},
{
"severity": "error",
"code": null,
"path": "beatstar.zip/beatstar.app/Contents/Frameworks/Squirrel.framework/Versions/A/Squirrel",
"message": "The binary is not signed with a valid Developer ID certificate.",
"docUrl": null,
"architecture": "x86_64"
},
{
"severity": "error",
"code": null,
"path": "beatstar.zip/beatstar.app/Contents/Frameworks/Squirrel.framework/Versions/A/Resources/ShipIt",
"message": "The binary is not signed with a valid Developer ID certificate.",
"docUrl": null,
"architecture": "x86_64"
},
{
"severity": "error",
"code": null,
"path": "beatstar.zip/beatstar.app/Contents/Frameworks/ReactiveCocoa.framework/Versions/A/ReactiveCocoa",
"message": "The binary is not signed with a valid Developer ID certificate.",
"docUrl": null,
"architecture": "x86_64"
},
{
"severity": "error",
"code": null,
"path": "beatstar.zip/beatstar.app/Contents/Frameworks/Mantle.framework/Versions/A/Mantle",
"message": "The binary is not signed with a valid Developer ID certificate.",
"docUrl": null,
"architecture": "x86_64"
},
{
"severity": "error",
"code": null,
"path": "beatstar.zip/beatstar.app/Contents/Frameworks/beatstar Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/beatstar Helper",
"message": "The binary is not signed with a valid Developer ID certificate.",
"docUrl": null,
"architecture": "x86_64"
},
{
"severity": "error",
"code": null,
"path": "beatstar.zip/beatstar.app/Contents/Frameworks/beatstar Helper (Plugin).app/Contents/MacOS/beatstar Helper (Plugin)",
"message": "The binary is not signed with a valid Developer ID certificate.",
"docUrl": null,
"architecture": "x86_64"
},
{
"severity": "error",
"code": null,
"path": "beatstar.zip/beatstar.app/Contents/Frameworks/beatstar Helper (Renderer).app/Contents/MacOS/beatstar Helper (Renderer)",
"message": "The binary is not signed with a valid Developer ID certificate.",
"docUrl": null,
"architecture": "x86_64"
}
]
}

Comment: This seems quite specific for that library. You may want to additionaly open an issue in the [github project](https://github.com/electron/electron-notarize). The first thing I see is this error message `The binary is not signed with a valid Developer ID certificate.` Did you use the right developer certificate?

Comment: Also to get a better picture of what you are doing - could you add your electron-builder configuration to your question?

Comment: ```
appId: "com.oriolgomez.beatstar"
"directories": {
  "output": "dist",
"buildResources": "build",
}
"afterSign": "build/notarize.js"
nodeGypRebuild: false
npmRebuild: false
win:
  target:
    - target: zip
      arch:
      - ia32
mac:
  "hardenedRuntime" : true
  "gatekeeperAssess": false
  "entitlements": "build/entitlements.mac.plist"
  "entitlementsInherit": "build/entitlements.mac.plist"
  target:
    - target: dmg
      arch:
                - x64


electronVersion: 10.1.3```

Comment: I don't develop on macOs, so I can't help any further. electron-builder has [documented](https://www.electron.build/code-signing) environment variables `CSC_NAME` and `CSC_KEYCHAIN`. Playing around with them might get you further.

Comment: Also it would be very nice, if you could add the content of your last comment to your question by using the 'edit' button. Comments are deleted regularly, so this information might get lost.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know if the reason I ran into this is the same as yours, but here's what I discovered, in case this helps anyone else.

Before manually notarizing your app (using electron-notarize), make sure the certificate **type** you're signing your app with is correct. You specifically need a `Developer ID Application` certificate (the last one):

[image: Apple Developer certificate type selection]

I had been using `Apple Distribution` before, and notarization failed because of it. The list of files you're seeing are probably the first few files Apple checked, and they were signed with an incorrect type of certificate (don't quote me on this), and so it failed.

Either way, once I generated an `Developer ID Application` certificate, defined my entitlements this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-jit</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-dyld-environment-variables</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.disable-library-validation</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

and used this config in the `build` section of my `package.json`:

```
    "mac": {
      "category": "public.app-category.developer-tools",
      "icon": "assets/icon.png",
      "hardenedRuntime": true,
      "gatekeeperAssess": false,
      "entitlements": "assets/mac/entitlements.plist",
      "entitlementsInherit": "assets/mac/entitlements.plist"
    },
    "afterSign": "./scripts/notarizeApp.js",
```

I was able to get notarization to work.

This is what my notarizeApp script looks like, FWIW:

```
const path = require('path')
var notarize = require('electron-notarize')

module.exports = async function (params) {
  // Notarization only applies to macOS
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    return
  }

  let appId = '<your-app-id>'
  let appPath = path.join(
    params.appOutDir,
    `${params.packager.appInfo.productFilename}.app`
  )

  try {
    console.log(`  • Notarizing`)
    await notarize.notarize({
      appBundleId: appId,
      appPath: appPath,
      appleId: process.env.APPLE_ID_EMAIL,
      appleIdPassword: process.env.APPLE_ID_PASSWORD,
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
}
```

This app was very useful to check if notarization was successful (Taccy):
https://eclecticlight.co/taccy-signet-precize-alifix-utiutility-alisma/